# Ubuntu 14.04: Hostname showing as ubuntu on router

Tags: networking, dns, hostname, static-ip

This is driving me crazy.

I have a **static IP** configured, Ethernet cabled Ubuntu Server 14.04 machine

Where you see **MY_HOSTNAME**, this is where I have configured my real hostname which is 5 characters long, all lower case with no special characters.

- `/etc/hostname` contains:

  `MY_HOSTNAME`
- `/etc/network/interfaces` contains:

  `hostname MY_HOSTNAME`
- `/etc/hosts` contains:

  `127.0.0.1    localhost`

  `127.0.1.1    MY_HOSTNAME`

I have run `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname MY_HOSTNAME`

So can someone tell me why my router is reporting my hostname as `ubuntu` (exactly like that in lower case)?

I have rebooted the server and the router a number of times.

When the router comes back online, it initially shows the server as UNKNOWN, then when I ping it from another network device or ssh to it, then the UNKNOWN changes to ubuntu.

Where is the router getting this name and where on the server do I change it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the router is displaying your hostname? Or is it detecting your os and using that?

Comment: Usually routers use the NetBIOS name, if it is available, otherwise they report a made-up name. Are you running a service such as Samba which would provide a NetBIOS name to the router? Otherwise, how would you expect the router to learn the host name of the machine?